# Move sprite over period of time

Tags: java, animation, 2d

I am making a 2d miner/adventure game, and I am trying to make the sun move across the screen.

How it should work is, it has to get from point A(top left of screen) to point B(top right of screen) in alignment with the time of day.

I found out how to do the math, but when I run the game, the sun sprite just doesnt budge. i even waited for night to fall and still, it doesnt budge. Im trying to figure out why it wont move.

I verified the math:

```
public int dayFrame = 0;
int u = 0;
int x;
int y = 36;
public int dayTime = 7500;


public void tick()
{
    x = (TritonForge.pixel.width / dayTime) * dayFrame;
    u += 1;
    if (u > 4)
    {
        dayFrame += 1;
        u = 0;
    }
    (rest of code...)
```

It gets the screen width in units, and divides it by the total amount of time the day has.
It then multiplies that by what time it is at the moment. I know this works because (TritonForge.pixel.width / dayTime) * dayTime = 640(the width of my screen in units).

```
public void render(Graphics gr)
{
    gr.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
    gr.fillRect(0, 0, TritonForge.pixel.width, TritonForge.pixel.height);
    gr.drawImage(TileArt.sun,x,y, null);
    gr.drawImage(TileArt.forestback,0,0, null);
    gr.drawImage(TileArt.foresttree,0,0, null);
}
```

can someone please help?

Comment: 1) What does this have to do with JavaScript?  Please make sure to *read* the helpful tag descriptions in the pop-ups before applying them to a question.  'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Assume a day has a length of 10 seconds. Adjust your program to have 10 seconds for the time frame. The start position is A and when you run the program, check if it goes to point B in 10 seconds. Debug from there.

Comment: this is made in java, does javascript mean something else or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with integer division. Your screen width is presumably `TritonForge.pixel.width`? When dividing this by `dayTime` it will probably always equal zero as your screen is not 7,500 pixels (again assuming here.)

This is because integer division rounds down to the nearest whole number.  Say your screen is 1200 pixels. 1200 / 7500 = .16. That rounds down to 0.

So instead change your code too...

```
double x;
x = (TritonForge.pixel.width / (double)dayTime) * dayFrame;
```

And cast x to an int as appropriate.